# webapi - db Migrations

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I tried to run my code after adding two new classes to the ef using web api 2, and i got the following error :

> The model backing the 'AuthContext' context has changed since the database was created.

When I tried to do "Enable-Migrations", i got the error :

> No MigrationSqlGenerator found for provider 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'.

I found a solution but it's a solution for MVC which is the following:

```
public Configuration()
{
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

// register mysql code generator
SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
}
```

The thing is I can't find where to put this piece of code in my web api project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to webapi is the same as a web MVC project.

1. First, you run command "enable-migrations" in the Package manage console. The the Migrations folder will be created in your project structure where you can find the Configuration.cs file.
2. Then inside the Configuration.cs file, add

   ```
   // register mysql code generator
   SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
   ```

into the constructor just below the line

```
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

That's all.